# Conditional counting across a row in pandas when matching a string

Tags: python, pandas, count, conditional-statements

I have pandas dataframe of the form,df=

```
index,result1,result2,result3 
  0     s       u       s     
  1     u       s       u   
  2     s                     
  3     s       s       u
```

i would like to add another column that contains a list of the number of times s occurs in that row, for example

```
index,result1,result2,result3,count 
  0     s       u       s      2
  1     u       s       u      1
  2     s                      1
  3     s       s       u      2
```

i have tried the following code

```
col=['result1','result2','result3']
df[cols].count(axis=1)
```

but this returns

```
0,3
1,3
2,1
3,3
```

so this counts the number of elements, i then tried

```
df[df[cols]=='s'].count(axis=1)
```

but this returned the following error: "Could not compare ['s'] with block values"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What are the missing values here? Are they blank strings or `NaN`? what does `df.info()` show? `df=='s'` will work if you have all str or mixed dtypes but if you have any pure numerical columns  or rows then this won't work, this will happen if you have any rows with all `NaN` You can try `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` then `(df[cols] = 's').count(axis=1)` should work

Comment: @WGP, Perhaps, `df['count'] = (df[cols].values=='s').sum(1)` would be a nice alternative?

Answer (score 2):

For me works cast to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) numeric and `NaN` columns return your `error`:

```
print (df)
   index result1 result2  result3  result4
0      0       s       u        7      NaN
1      1       u       s        7      NaN
2      2       s     NaN        8      NaN
3      3       s       s        7      NaN
4      4     NaN     NaN        2      NaN

print (df.dtypes)
index        int64
result1     object
result2     object
result3      int64
result4    float64
dtype: object

cols = ['result1','result2','result3','result4']
df['count'] = df[df[cols].astype(str) == 's'].count(axis=1)
print (df)
   index result1 result2  result3  result4  count
0      0       s       u        7      NaN      1
1      1       u       s        7      NaN      1
2      2       s     NaN        8      NaN      1
3      3       s       s        7      NaN      2
4      4     NaN     NaN        2      NaN      0
```

Or [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) only `True` values from `boolean mask`:

```
print (df[cols].astype(str) == 's')

  result1 result2 result3 result4
0    True   False   False   False
1   False    True   False   False
2    True   False   False   False
3    True    True   False   False
4   False   False   False   False

cols = ['result1','result2','result3','result4']
df['count'] = (df[cols].astype(str) =='s').sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   index result1 result2  result3  result4  count
0      0       s       u        7      NaN      1
1      1       u       s        7      NaN      1
2      2       s     NaN        8      NaN      1
3      3       s       s        7      NaN      2
4      4     NaN     NaN        2      NaN      0
```

Another nice solution is from [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546462/conditional-counting-across-a-row-in-pandas-when-matching-a-string#comment68331769_40546462) - use `numpy`:

```
df['count'] = (df[cols].values=='s').sum(axis=1)
```